# Can we do multiple nesting in SQL Server using FOR JSON AUTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, subquery, for-json

Here is my table and data

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
   ID int,
   name varchar(255),
   root_id int,
   level_id int,
   description nvarchar(max),
   language_id int
);

INSERT INTO category (ID, name, root_id, level_id, description, language_id)
VALUES (1, 'questionnaire', 0, 1, 'desc1', 1);
VALUES (2, 'category1', 1, 2, 'desc1', 1);
VALUES (3, 'subcategory1', 2, 3, 'desc1', 1);
VALUES (4, 'subcategory_ge1', 2, 3, 'desc1', 2);
VALUES (5, 'subcategory2', 2, 3, 'desc2', 1);
VALUES (6, 'subcategory_ge2', 2, 3, 'desc2', 2);
VALUES (7, 'category2', 1, 2, 'desc2', 1);
VALUES (8, 'category2_ge', 1, 2, 'desc2', 2);
VALUES (9, 'subcategory3', 7, 3, 'desc3', 1);
VALUES (10, 'subcategory4', 8, 3, 'desc4', 1);
```

I am trying to fetch the data to get the format like

```
   ID          name        root_id     level_id    questionnare_data
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    1      questionnaire        1           0       {"categories":{{"ID:2,"name":"category1","level_id":2,"subcategories":{{"ID":3,"name":"subcategory1","level_id":3},{"ID":4,"name":"subcategory_ge1","level_id":3},{"ID":5,"name":"subcategory2","level_id":3},{"ID":6,"name":"subcategory_ge2","level_id":3}}},{"ID":7",name":"category2","level_id":2,"subcategories":{{"ID":9,"name":"subcategory3","level_id":3}}},{"ID":8",name":"category2_ge","level_id":2,"subcategories":{{"ID":10,"name":"subcategory4","level_id":3}}}}}
```

I have tried the below query

```
select  A.ID, A.name, A.level_id , A.root_id ,
(select B.ID, B.name,
(select C.ID, C.name
from  category as C
where  C.level_id=2 and C.root_id=B.ID FOR JSON AUTO) AS subcategories
from  category as B
where  B.level_id=1 and B.root_id=A.ID FOR JSON AUTO) AS categories
from category as A
where A.level_id=0 and A.root_id IS NULL
```

I am getting somewhat a desired output. But my question is can I write the nested queries as such? does it cause any issue when there is large data?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, presumably you instead meant to use array brackets `[]` on the outside like so `{"categories":[{"ID:2...`

Comment: @Charlieface I am getting the output something like [{"ID":2,"level_id":1,"d2":[{"name":"category1","subcategories":[{"ID":3,"level_id":3,"d1":[{"name":"subcategory1"}]},{"ID":6,"level_id":2,"d1":[{"name":"subcategory2"}]},{"ID":6,"level_id":2,"d1":[{"name":"subcategory_ge1"}]}]}]},{"ID":7,"level_id":1,"d2":[{"name":"category2"}.... But  my main concern is that the way the query written is a right approach?

Comment: Pretty much the only approach you can do, without resorting to a loop. I personally prefer `CROSS APPLY` instead of a subquery inside the `SELECT`, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0499e21e2c25bba3d0b80fcaa373da5. Personal preference though. You would definitely need some kind of loop or recursive CTE if you want to descend up to any level

Comment: @Charlieface I am getting an error like l3 has more columns than specified in column list

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query.

The following query has one main select and 3 internal select.

Its structure is as follows :

```
select data,(select 
              josnData,
              (select josnData,
                      (select josnData from category where level_id = 3) as subcategories  
               from category where level_id = 2) as categories
             from category where level_id = 1) as questionnare_data
from category where level_id = 1
```

query

```
select ID, name, level_id , root_id,
   (select (select ID, name, level_id , root_id,(select ID, name, level_id , root_id from category where level_id=3 FOR JSON PATH) as subcategories from category where level_id=2 FOR JSON PATH) as categories
   from category where level_id=1 FOR JSON PATH) as questionnare_data
from category
where level_id=1
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5816d82dbad8b57aba1469313aaf3ec3)

Comment: is this more efficient way than cross apply?

Comment: I can't get output with cross apply either.

Comment: @Saisri It's exactly the same performance as `cross apply` because it is also correlated, see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0499e21e2c25bba3d0b80fcaa373da5